# Core dumped utilizando malloc

Tags: c

Hola buenas hace unos dias me paso que ocurria un core dumped en un programa, lo solucione y funcionaba pero al añadir un malloc me vulve a hacer lo mismo por favor ayuda adjunto codigo

```
char *aux;
    char *token;

    fd = fopen(filename, "r");
    /*if (cont == (tamano - 1))
    {
      cell = (CELDA *)realloc(cell, tamano + 5);
      tamano = tamano + 5;
    }*/
    do
    {
      //Guarda ID
      getline(&aux, &max_num, fd);
      if (feof(fd)) //comprueba que ya no haya mas lineas en el archivo
        break;

      token = strtok(aux, " ");
      token = strtok(NULL, " ");
      strcpy(cell[cont].id, token);

      //Guarda ESSID
      getline(&aux, &max_num, fd);
      token = strtok(aux, ":");
      token = strtok(NULL, ":");
      strcpy(cell[cont].essid, token);

      cont++;

      if (cont == (tamano - 1))
    {
      cell = (CELDA *)realloc(cell, tamano + 5);
      tamano = tamano + 5;
    }

    } while (!feof(fd));
    fclose(fd);
```

creo que asi no deberia dar un core dumped pero me sigue dando que puede ser?
como se ve le he puesto una condicion que vaya aumentando el tamaño segun se acaban el espacio

Comment: Has considerado liberar la memoria que asignas mediante `free()`??

Comment: si pero sigue sin funcionar, no se cual es el problema si de forma modular todo va bien se supone

Comment: Comparte un ejemplo minimo porfavor. Para esta clase de errores usualemente tenemos que probar el codigo en nuestras maquinas. Publica suficiente codigo como para que pueda copiar y pegar en mi editor, y ver el error. Con lo que compartes simplemente no es posible de momento.

Comment: vale perfecto ahora lo subo pero no se como poner solo codigo en la plataforma para que no me lo tire